# Update Fullcalendar event after creation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

When I create a new event, i POST it on the server with a tastypie REST API. When created, this event on the server has a new id, generated when is saved:

```
select: function (startDate, endDate, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

    /* after selection user will be promted for enter title for event.*/

    var title = prompt('Event Title:');

    /*if title is enterd calendar will add title and event into fullCalendar. */

}
if (title) {
    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
            title: title,
            start: startDate,
            end: endDate,
            allDay: allDay
        },
        true // make the event "stick"
    );
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/calendar/api/events/events/',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; encode=UTF-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            title: title,
            start: startDate,
            end: endDate,
            allDay: allDay,
            user: "/calendar/api/events/users/{{ user.id }}/"
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            // Could i do something here?

        }
    });
    console.log({{user.id}},'{{ user}}')

}

},
```

I need to update the event on the client memory, because the event just created, has an event id like "fc_1" or something similar, but i need the DB id, because if i immediately drag o resize the event, i can't update it on server because it will try to PUT this event, but with the wrong id (like "fc_1").

Answer (score 2):

in your renderEvent object, you could add id: 'pending'. Then in your success function you can use the fullcalendar [clientEvents](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) function to get the array of events and then use [updateEvent](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/updateEvent/) to add your new id value:

```
success: function(data) {
    var newID = data.id;
    var events = calendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
        if(events[i].id == 'pending') {
            events[i].id = newID;
            calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', events[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could run into latency problems if you try to resize the event too quick and the callback function hasn't fired yet.  You might want to disable dragging in the select function and turn it on again in the callback.  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/editable/